# How can I access private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**base.rb**

```
module Search
  class Base

    attr_accessor :query_model
    attr_accessor :result

    def initialize(query_obj)
      self.query_model = query_obj
    end

    def execute         
    end

  end
end
```

**social_mention.rb**

```
module Search
  class SocialMention < Base

    def execute
      self.result = RestClient.get api_client, :params => query_params
      parse_result
    end

    private

    def api_client
      'http://socialmention.com/search'
    end
end
```

How can I access **api_client** method  ?

I'm following this but didn't access it.

```
Search::SocialMention.new(query).api_client
```

What is the correct way to access private method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do external access to private methods via the `Object#send` method:

```
Search::SocialMention.new(query).send(:api_client)
```

But since you want to access it outside, why do you put it as private at first?